# Integrate function of a Gaussian white noise process w.r.t. time?

Tags: probability, integration, definite-integrals, stochastic-processes, stochastic-integrals

Let $X(t)$ be a Gaussian white noise process with mean zero and variance $\sigma^2 \in \mathbb{R}$. Let $\tau \in \mathbb{R}$ be a constant. How would I identify the distribution of $$I = \int_0^t X(u) e^{u/\tau} \, du$$ where $t \in \mathbb{R}$ denotes time?

EDIT: Having read [What is meant by a continuous-time white noise process?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/134193/what-is-meant-by-a-continuous-time-white-noise-process), it looks like it is more correct to write $$I = \int_0^t \sigma e^{u/\tau} \, dB_u$$ where $B_u$ denotes Brownian motion.

EDIT 2: Using the Ito Isometry to evaluate the variance of $I$ I get $$\mathbb{E}\left[\left(\int_0^t \sigma e^{u/\tau} \, dB_u\right)^2\right] = \mathbb{E}\left[\int_0^t \sigma^2 e^{2u/\tau} \, du\right]= \dfrac{\sigma^2 \tau}{2}\left(e^{2t/\tau}-1\right).$$ I would guess that the expectation of $I$ is zero since each of the normal random variables in the series has mean zero, but how does this follow from the Ito isometry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume your integral is an [Ito integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%C3%B4_calculus). You can see $I$ as the stochastic limit of a series of normal random variables; so $I$ has a Normal distribution.

In addition, it is a Martingale and
$$ \mathbf{E}[I_t] = \mathbf{E}[I_0] = 0$$

Then, you can apply [Ito isometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%C3%B4_isometry) to find the the variance of $I$.

Comment: Thanks. I have responded to your answer in my question.

Comment: You're welcome! Sorry I didn't point it out. Ito integrals have zero mean.

Comment: Does the $dB_u$ notation imply that the variance of the white noise process is equal to one? If so, am I correct in multiplying the integrand by sigma?

Comment: Yes that is correct. $B_t$ is a Brownian motion with variance $t$.